# Initialise the edit form with the values from the Cloud Firestore document

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have two components list-doctor and edit-doctor.
In the list-doctor the documents are displayed in a data table. For each Row I added a button edit that opens the edit-doctor component. At click on the edit button it opens the edit-doctor page and I want the form to be initialised with the data from database.
[image]
[image]

This is the way I tried after watching this tutorial:
https://www.remotestack.io/angular-firebase-firestore-real-time-crud-example-tutorial/

```js
//list-doctor.component.ts
export class ListDoctorComponent implements OnInit {
  Doctors : Doctor[];
  doctorID: any;
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.db
      .collection("doctors")
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.Doctors = res.map(e => {
          return {
            id: e.payload.doc.id,
            ...e.payload.doc.data() as Doctor
          }
        })
      });
  }

  removeDoctor = doctor => this.db.collection("doctors").doc(doctor.id).delete()
}

//edit-doctor.component.ts
export class EditDoctorComponent implements OnInit {
  public formData: FormGroup;
  userRef: any;
  
  constructor(
    public doctorInfoService: DoctorInfoService,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private act: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    ) {

      this.formData = this.formBuilder.group({
        doctorName: [''],
        category: ['']
        })
    }
   
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const doctorID = this.act.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.db.collection("doctors").doc(doctorID)
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe( (res :any) => {
      this.userRef = res;
           
      this.formData = this.formBuilder.group({
        doctorName: [this.userRef.doctorName],
        category: [this.userRef.category]
      })
    })
  }
  onSubmit(){}
}
```

```html
<!-- list-doctor.component.html -->
<button routerLink="/admin">Back</button>
<button routerLink="/create-doctor">Add Doctor</button>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let doctor of Doctors; let i = index">
            <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
          <td>{{ doctor.doctorID }}</td>
          <td>{{ doctor.doctorName }}</td>
          <td>{{ doctor.category }}</td>
          <td>
            <span (click)="removeDoctor(doctor)" class="text-danger">Delete</span> &nbsp;
            
            <span routerLink="/edit-doctor/{{doctor.doctorID}}" class="text-primary">Edit</span>
          </td>
</table>


<!-- edit-doctor.component.html -->
<form [formGroup]="formData" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="doctorName" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label>Category</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="category" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  
    <div class="mb-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And I get errors at this two lines with the message "Cannot read property 'doctorName' of undefined"

```js
this.formData = this.formBuilder.group({
        doctorName: [this.userRef.doctorName],
        category: [this.userRef.category]
      })
    })
```

I tried different examples and if I add some input test values instead of `this.userRef.doctorName` it shows correctly:

```js
export class EditDoctorComponent implements OnInit { 
...
 ngOnInit(): void {
    const doctorID = this.act.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.db.collection("doctors").doc(doctorID)
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe( (res :any) => {
      this.userRef = res;
           
      this.formData = this.formBuilder.group({
        doctorName: ['Dr Hart'],
        category: ['Cardiologists']
      })
    })

  }
}
```

In this way the form is initialised
[image]

This is the database collection
[image]

I'm looking for a solution to initialise the form at click on edit.
I appreciate any guidance or help. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked by doing console.log(this.userRef) to verify it is not empty before loading it inside the form. or to avoid errors you can try like  doctorName: [this.userRef?.doctorName], category: [this.userRef?.category]

Comment: in conosole.log(this.userRef) it returns undefined